# wp_nav_menu not working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a theme for my wordpress blog, I am struct on the code to display custom menus

in my functions.php I have wrote:

```
function register_my_menus(){
register_nav_menus(
    array('menu-1' => __('Primary Menu'),
    )
);
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');
```

this is my header.php

```
 if ( has_nav_menu( $location ) ) {
     wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1'));
 }
```

the problem is that when I am setting a menu from wordpress to Primary Menu, no menu is displaying and also the content after menu is not displaying, please help me where I am wrong

Comment: register_nav_menus  is used for multiple menus, use register_nav_menu

Answer (score 1):

You've used the has_nav_menu() command, by the looks of it, copy/pasted from the Codex, without giving it a parameter.  Try this:

Instead of

```
if ( has_nav_menu( $location ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1'));
}
```

This:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'menu-1' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1'));
}
```

Then, provided you've actually made a menu for the location in the admin panel, and assigned it to this location, it should work as far as I can see.

Comment: I noticed that, this problem is with every theme, so I need to look other code to solve the problem

Comment: Apologies for the potentially silly question but, is the menu empty or unassigned?

Answer (score 1):

Hi mandeep singh did you assign your menu to the Primary Menu in the wordpress admin pannel

Comment: Thank you. In my case it was so weird, I had to click on the 'add menu' button in the backend. Even though the menu was already defined including menu items. Afterwards I could select 'Primary'. Now the theme filters like 'wp_nav_menu' suddenly work as expected.